# "By pencil" vs "in pencil"

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Is there any difference between "The letter was written ***by*** pencil" and "The letter was written ***in*** pencil" ?

Comment: Are you expecting there to be a difference?

Comment: ***in pencil*** (idiom)

: by using a pencil. - 
*Write your answers in pencil.* https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/in%20pencil#:~:text=Definition%20of%20in%20pencil,Write%20your%20answers%20in%20pencil.

Comment: @KillingTime I don't know. That's why i am asking to know there is the difference or there is not :)

Comment: The letter wasn't written by a pencil, but by a person, in pencil. It's clearer if you use the word 'ink' instead of 'pencil'.

Comment: @WeatherVane - But a letter written in pencil is not written in ink. From that point of view it’s written in graphite.

Comment: @Jim I meant it would be clearer to understand the grammar, not how writing implements work.

Comment: @WeatherVane - *Ohhh!* gotcha. Ok, so for OP’s sake: “The difference might be more discernible if you think about the two options using the word ‘ink’ instead of ‘pencil’.

Comment: 'by pencil' describes the instrument used, but 'in pencil' is describing the medium.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no question that the usual expression is *written in pencil*, as shown by an Ngram that makes *by pencil* seem nonexistent:

[image]

[image]

> **pencil** (n.)
>
> Work executed with a pencil; graphite or a similar substance used as
> a medium for writing or drawing. Chiefly as **in pencil**.
>
> **1796**   M. G. Lewis *Monk* II. iv. 33   A small note, addressed to me... It contained the following words, **written in pencil**. (OED online)

Earlier:

> ...I immediately after wrote down with pencil the substance of what he
> had said; this he afterwards amplified and corrected; these scraps of
> paper, **written in pencil**, I have either mislaid or destroyed, but
> recollect to have seen them since my arrival in England; ...
> [Alexander Dalrymple; *A reply to a "Letter from Andrew Stuart, Esq;
> to the Hon. the directors of the East-India Company"*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_Reply_to_a_Letter_from_Andrew_Stuart_E/cysnJ4D6GDIC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22written%20in%20pencil%22&pg=PA75&printsec=frontcover)  (1776)

---

> **by** (prep.)
>
> With the use or help of; through: *We came **by** the back road*.
>
> Through the agency or action of: *was killed **by** a bullet*. [AHD](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=by)

However **by pen/pencil** has been used, very infrequently, apparently when the author wanted to emphasize the means of writing (*by means of* or *using a pen/pencil*) over a description of the appearance of the writing, e.g., *It's hard to tell from the photo, but it appears to be written in pencil*.

Perhaps the better cases for using *by* in the following examples are:  (1) "20 times faster than they can be written **by** pen or typewriter," where the *by* is clearly **by means of**. *In* doesn't sound right in this case for *pencil*, and we wouldn't  say **written in typewriter*. (2) "This is the first time this beautiful word [America] was ever **written by pen** or engraved **by** tool or stamped **by** type."

---

Note that  *written by pen* has been used to mean simply *authored* or *penned*, without regard to the implement:

> I call the Book of Job, apart from all theories about it, one of the
> grandest things ever **written by pen**. [John Fritz; *Theological
> Monthly, Vol. 2, p.77*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Theological_Monthly/sBpKAAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22ever%20written%20by%20pen%22&pg=PA77&printsec=frontcover) (1922) [Setting aside the question of who authored it and how.]

---

> Steinbeck used 300 pencils to write his novel *East of Eden.*
> Typewriters existed then, but Steinbeck preferred to **write by
> pencil.** [Brianne Keith; *American Lit 101*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/American_Lit_101/Pt2WDgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22write%20by%20pencil%22&pg=PA185&printsec=frontcover) (2017)

> Most of my poetry started out **written by pen or pencil** on whatever
> paper was available at the time, such as paper napkins (accompanying a
> coffee and the compulsory cookie or cake), or the inside of a emptied
> breakfast cereal box. [Wayne Pendelton; *The Closet Poet's
> Collection*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Closet_Poet_s_Collection/TvACBwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=all%20the%20prose%20%22written%20by%20pen%22&pg=PT68&printsec=frontcover) (2015)

> For example, when a modern orchestra plays a Mozart symphony, a large
> number of detailed instructions have to be **written by pencil** into
> the score. [*Hungarian Music Guide, Issues 19-20, p.89*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Hungarian_Musical_Guide/1y5MAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22written%20by%20pencil%22&dq=%22written%20by%20pencil%22&printsec=frontcover) (1982)
> (Snippet view)

> The question must be **written by pencil** (or at least by chemical
> pencil), legible, the words must be written completely without
> corrections, if it is possible. [Edward Perdue; *Lost Adventures*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Lost_Adventures/qKxsc2Oz8mkC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22written%20by%20pencil%22&pg=PA435&printsec=frontcover)
> (2005)

> This is the first time this beautiful word [*America*] was ever
> **written by pen** or engraved by tool or stamped by type. [John Thacher; *The Continent of America*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Continent_of_America/9r11AAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22ever%20written%20by%20pen%22&dq=%22ever%20written%20by%20pen%22&printsec=frontcover) (1971)

> **pencil footing** a temporary total underneath a list of figures **written by pencil.**  [Guy Wanjialin; *An International Dictionary of Accounting and Taxation*](https://books.google.com/books?id=t8wXE8ybptUC&newbks=0&printsec=frontcover&pg=PA288&dq=%22written%20by%20pencil%22&hl=en&source=newbks_fb#v=onepage&q=%22written%20by%20pencil%22&f=false)  (2004)

> A will was disapproved where it was **written by pencil** and the
> scrivener and attesting witnesses were all persons benefitting from
> the purported will. [US Dept. of the Interior; *Digest of Indian
> Probate Law*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Digest_of_Federal_Indian_Probate_Law/3mdAAAAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22written%20by%20pencil%22&pg=PA91&printsec=frontcover) (1972)

> The call number would have been **written by pencil** on the page
> following the title page and book pocket would have been pasted inside
> the book cover. [Slade Gandert; *Protecting Your Collection*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Protecting_Your_Collection/Nh_mOoM0HwQC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22written%20by%20pencil%22&pg=PA124&printsec=frontcover)
> (1982)

> However, the number of revisions in essays that were **begun by pen** and
> revised on the computer approached that in essays **written by pen**.
> [*Resources in Education, Vol. 24, Issues 1-3, p.46*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Resources_in_Education/fqtfdqsrNJoC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22written%20by%20pen%22&pg=RA1-PA46&printsec=frontcover) (1989)

> An indorsement **written by pencil** is sufficient, and it may be by a
> mark or with the figures 1-2-8 with no name, ... [*McKinney's
> Consolidated Law of New York Annotated*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/McKinney_s_Consolidated_Laws_of_New_York/LSoqAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22written%20by%20pencil%22&dq=%22written%20by%20pencil%22&printsec=frontcover) (1991) (Snippet view)

> The ADDRESSOGRAPH addresses and takes care of lists of names of every
> nature. It saves time and labor by ...  —at the rate of 60 a minute—
> 20 times faster than they can be **written by pen or typewriter.**
> [*Factory*, Vol. 13, p.387](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Factory_the_Magazine_of_Management/r-M7AQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22written%20by%20pen%20or%20typewriter%22&pg=PA387&printsec=frontcover) (1914)

> The gelatin duplicators are used when 50 or less copies are needed.
> The material to be reproduced is either **written by pen or
> typewriter** with regular copying ink. It requires very little
> instruction to learn to operate this simple appliance. [Frank
> McClelland; *Office Training and Standards*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Office_Training_and_Standards/kDEaAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22written%20by%20pen%20or%20typewriter%22&pg=PA25&printsec=frontcover) (1919)

---

Some verbs accept two or more prepositions more commonly:

> In the country, people often make their own ink, and make it badly ,
> the characters written by which are not so legible as those **made by
> pencil**. [*Pennsylvania State Reports*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Pennsylvania_State_Reports_Containing_Ca/EeDzAAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22made%20by%20pencil%22&pg=PA169&printsec=frontcover) (1869)

> Some late alterations are then **made in pencil** again. [‎David
> Clark; *W.B. Yeats, the Writing of Sophocles' King Oedipus*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/W_B_Yeats_the_Writing_of_Sophocles_King/tzoLAAAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22made%20in%20pencil%22&pg=PA265&printsec=frontcover) 
> (1989)

> When it is necessary to blend or smudge drawings **made with
> pencil**, charcoal, or pastel medium a stump is used. [US Bureau of
> Navy Personnel; *Illustrator Draftsman 3 & 2, p.55*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Illustrator_Draftsman_3_2/qxreN7uTewsC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22made%20with%20pencil%22&pg=PA55&printsec=frontcover) (1972)

Comment: Can you give an explanation? This is misleading since the usual way of saying it is "This letter is written in pencil".

Comment: @Mitch  I've added an Ngram to show that the standard expression is indeed *written in pen/pencil*. From the examples, it seems that *by* was chosen to emphasize the process of writing over the usual more descriptive use (appearance), as in *written in pencil with small, printed letters.*

Comment: Thanks. Implicitly that suggests that the two pretty much mean the same thing but 'by' is a rare variant. Is that the feeling you get? I suppose 'by' means for me something a little more literal, almost an implied 'by using a'.

Comment: @Mitch Yes, I wrote that the connotation seems to be  "by means of or using a pen/pencil", emphasizing the act of writing with a pencil as the writing tool.

Comment: And it’s different from “written by candlelight” too.  :-)

Comment: @Jim Yes, *it was written by John by pencil by heart  by  candlelight by fits and starts, by gosh.*